# Client segreto in Google Developer

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2019

I have to publish a new app in the Google Play Store. I use Xamarin.Forms in Visual Studio 2019.

I have created the App in the Console Google Developer.

I have already SH1, client Id as from this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/publishing/publishing-to-google-play/?tabs=windows

Now I need to get the Secret client.

But in the Console Google Developer there is not the "Secret Client".

I see in Visual Studio 2019 when I publish the app, (in the section Archive), there is a window with a textbox for insert the Secret Client. I tried to leave blank but don't works.

I need to have this Secret Client. Please see this article https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Google-Developer-Console-Generate-Client-ID-and-Client-Secret-for-use-with-Google-APIs.aspx

How can I get this secret client to insert in Visual Studio?
[Windows in Visual Studio 2019](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y7c84.png)I don't understand if it's been removed, but there is not.

Answer (score 0):

Android and ios apps don't have client secrets from Google, even though they're sometimes mentioned incorrectly in the google docs.